# Box-Cox, log or arcsine transformation?

Tags: modeling, data-transformation

Box-Cox, log and arcsine transformations have the aim of make the data more Normal. My question is: how can I choose between each one of these transformations? Which assumptions do I need to have to do that?

Normally I see people trying these transformations when modeling and simply picking the one which better performs - without any strong assumption or theory behind that.

I'm not so versatile in statistics but I'm trying to further understand it.

Comment: (1) The log *is* a Box-Cox transformation.  (2) There's plenty of theory: see the original papers and textbooks on EDA c. 1970-1990.  For an example, see our thread at 
 https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10975 and threads on Box-Cox transformations at https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Box-cox.

Comment: Do you have some context? This is to unspecific for an answer, see [this long list of similar posts](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:https://stats.stackexchange.com+how+choose+transformation&safe=off&client=ubuntu&hs=Q26&sxsrf=ALeKk02w7I57WE9X9knonN1N6rcrYW4LQw:1601657273487&ei=uVl3X8z1HPS55OUP6M6TiAk&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiMttmmrpbsAhX0HLkGHWjnBJEQ8NMDegQICxBG&biw=1232&bih=607). As for the arcsine  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20772/are-ecologists-the-only-ones-who-didnt-know-that-the-arcsine-is-asinine